# How to display uploaded picture immediately inside submition form (CodeIgniter)?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I want to create form where users can add products to database. They have to upload picture and choose couple of options from select boxes. So far I have my controller and view working fine - I validate both the upload and select boxes, set values to select boxes if some error accoured.

However, I want my users to be able to see uploaded picture and do some manipulations if necessary (rotate, crop - I am pretty sure that I know how to do that so it is not the question here) before submitting hole form.

The desired steps would look something like this:

1. There is button "upload picture" OR picture gets uploaded automatically. (if there is button I have to change validation settings for upload)
2. Picture is dynamically displayed to user ( have some ideas how to do it but I can not test them because of missing first step)
3. User does some manipulation
4. If user exits before submitting I delete uploaded picture (pretty sure I can handle this one)

Here is my code so far
Controller:

```
public function create()
        {
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('health', 'Health', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('manufacturer', 'Manufacturer', 'required');
            if (empty($_FILES['product']['name']))
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('product', 'Document', 'required');
            }

            $data['manufacturer'] = $this->input->get('manufacturer');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
            {
                $data['head'] = $this->load->view('templates/head', NULL, TRUE);
                $data['navmenu'] = $this->load->view('templates/navmenu', NULL, TRUE);
                $this->load->view('products/create', $data);
            }
            else
            {
                $user_id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();

                $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['file_name']            = $user_id;
                $config['max_size']             = 100;
                $config['max_width']            = 1024;
                $config['max_height']           = 768;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('product'))
                {
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                        $this->load->view('products/create', $error);
                }
                else
                {
                        $this->products_model->set_products();
                        $id = $this->db->insert_id();
                        $image_data = $this->upload->data();
                        $image['image_url'] = $image_data['file_name'];
                        $this->db->where ('product_id', $id);
                        $this->db->update('products', $image);
                        $this->load->view('products/success');
                }
            }
        }
```

and view:

```
<html>
        <head>
                <?=$head?>
        </head>
        <body>
                <?=$navmenu?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('products/create'); ?>

    <input type="file" name="product" size="20" />
    <?php echo form_error('product'); ?><br />
    <br /><br />

    <label for="health">Health</label>
    <select name="health">
        <option disabled selected value> -- select a health option -- </option>
        <option value="new">New</option>
        <option value="used">Used</option>
    </select>
    <?php echo form_error('health'); ?><br />

    <label for="manufacturer">Manufacturer</label>
    <select name="manufacturer" >
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an manufacturer -- </option>
        <option value="manufacturer1" <?php echo set_select('manufacturer','manufacturer1', ( !empty($manufacturer) && $manufacturer == "manufacturer1" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?> >Manufacturer1</option>
        <option value="manufacturer2" <?php echo set_select('manufacturer','manufacturer2', ( !empty($manufacturer) && $manufacturer == "manufacturer2" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?> >Manufacturer2</option>
        <option value="manufacturer3" <?php echo set_select('manufacturer','manufacturer3', ( !empty($manufacturer) && $manufacturer == "manufacturer3" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?> >Manufacturer3</option>
        <option value="manufacturer4" <?php echo set_select('manufacturer','manufacturer4', ( !empty($manufacturer) && $manufacturer == "manufacturer4" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?> >Manufacturer4</option>
    </select>
    <?php echo form_error('manufacturer'); ?><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create product item" />
</form>
```

Sorry If code is unclean in some places - it`s in development proceses. I have tried to split form into two but really lost in controllers code. General idea, pseidocode - anything that would get me on right track would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jquery To Do This

```
function ShowImage(input) {

if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#imgpreview').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}

$("#imgupload").change(function(){
    ShowImage(this);
});
```

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type='file' id="imgupload" />
    <img id="imgpreview" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

Comment: While this works great because I even do not have to delete picture if users exits without submitting there might be problem. I intended to use CI image library together with jQuery JCrop plugin but CI library requires source path for image. Using your answer means that I would have to use JCrop plugin to crop #imgpreview but I am not sure if the change will be uploaded. Could I target input as well?

Comment: what do you mean by `target input`

Comment: I guess I don`t get where is upload picture stored before submitting form. I want to perform jQuery methods on #imgpreview like rotation or croping. If I rotate the picture, how to ensure that rotated picture is uploaded on submit not the original?